# Securing Eclipse RAP application

Tags: eclipse, security, rcp

I have this application built in RCP/RAP and now I want to add security to it. I found out about the equinox security but this is only on application level.

Since I registered some http resources which are javascript applications, these are public available when connecting to the server. I want to protect these resources also with authentication.

Does anybody know how to protect these resources? Should I do this on server level or something?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This tutorial should provide you with some answers or at least a good start:
http://wiki.eclipse.org/RAP/Equinox_Security_Integration

Answer (score 0):

if deploy your RAP application as a WAR file (using Equinox servlet bridge) you can use all security mechanisms provided by your web container. Here is some info on how to do such deployment: http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.rap.help%2Fhelp%2Fhtml%2Fgetting-started%2Flauncher.html